# Pandas one-line filtering for the entire dataset - how is it achieved?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am just now diving into this wonderful library and am pretty baffled by how filtering, or even column manipulation, is done and am trying to understand if this is a feature of pandas or of python itself. More precisely:

```py
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')

# Doing
df['Column'] # would display all values from Column for dataframe

# Even moreso, doing
df.loc[df['Column'] > 10] # would display all values from Column greater than 10

# and is the same with
df.loc[df.Column > 10]
```

So columns are both attributes, and keys, so DataFrame is both a dict, and object? Or perhaps I am missing some basic python functionality that I don't know about... And accessing a column basically loops over the whole dataset? How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column filtering or column manipulation or overall data manipulation in a data set is a feature of pandas library itself. Once you load your data using pd.read_csv, the data set is stored as a pandas dataframe in a dictionary-like container. Then ,every column of dataframe is a series object of pandas. It depends on how you're trying to access the column, whether as an attribute(df.columnname) or a key(df['columnname']). Though you can apply methods like .head() or .tail() or .shape or .isna() on both the ways it is accessed. While accessing a certain column, it goes through whole dataset and tries to match the column name you have input. If it is matched, output is shown or else it throws some KeyError or AttributeError depends on how you're accessing it.